# Why when I import data from JTable to an Excel file within the NetBeans environment, does the program execute correctly and when I execute the same

Tags: java

Why when I import data from JTable to an Excel file within the NetBeans environment, does the program execute correctly
and when I execute the same program from the jar file, it does not import the data to the Excel file.

I tried with this button to import data from JTable to excel file:

```
public void openFile (String file)
        
{
    try {
    File path = new File(file);
        
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(path);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
    
} 


private void jButton17ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    
    //FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Reports\\Alkhaled\\excelfile\\data.xlsx"));
    
    //String path = "D:\\Reports\\Alkhaled\\excelfile\\data.xlsx";

    
          try{
              
              
        String path = "D:\\Reports\\Alkhaled\\excelfile\\data.xlsx";
        FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(new File(path));     

        JFileChooser JF = new JFileChooser();
        JF.showSaveDialog(jt);
        File savefile = JF.getSelectedFile();

        if(savefile != null)
        {
            savefile = new File (savefile.toString()+".xlsx");
            //savefile = new File (savefile.toString()+"D:\\Reports\\Alkhaled\\excelfile\\.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

            XSSFRow dataRow = sheet.createRow(0);
            for (int i=0; i < SerchVisa.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                XSSFCell cell = dataRow.createCell(i);
                cell.setCellValue(SerchVisa.getColumnName(i));

            }

            for (int j=0; j < SerchVisa.getRowCount(); j++)  {

                XSSFRow rowCell = sheet.createRow(j+1);
                for (int k=0; k < SerchVisa.getColumnCount(); k++) {
                    XSSFCell cell = rowCell.createCell(k);
                    cell.setCellValue(SerchVisa.getValueAt(j, k).toString());
                    if(SerchVisa.getValueAt(j,k) != null)   {
                        cell.setCellValue(SerchVisa.getValueAt(j, k).toString());

                    }

                }

            }

            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(savefile.toString()))) {
                workbook.write(out);
                workbook.close();
            }
            openFile(savefile.toString());
        }else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "خطأ في تحميل الملف");
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println(e);

    }  catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }



    
}
```